# Puppeteer get information about page loaded - list of files loaded and their sizes

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, puppeteer

I am wondering if it's possible to list of all the files loaded for a web page loaded through Google's Puppeteer e.g scripts, styles (not including inline), images, videos, audio. I need to get list of the files plus their respective sizes. Is that possible and if not is there some kind of software (e.g npm package) that might do that?

Searching Google and NPM results in nothing like what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page assets are not stored on disk, they are held in browser memory and sometimes cached, so it's impossible to know their sizes.

What you want to look at is web scraping, which can be done with modules like [node-website-scraper](https://github.com/website-scraper/node-website-scraper) or [with puppeteer](https://fettblog.eu/scraping-with-puppeteer/) :

```
page.on('response', async (response) => {
    const url = new URL(response.url());
    let filePath = path.resolve(`./output${url.pathname}`);
    if (path.extname(url.pathname).trim() === '') {
      filePath = `${filePath}/index.html`;
    }
    await fs_extra.outputFile(filePath, await response.buffer());
  });
```

The piece of code above will intercept requests and save them in an output folder, where you can check their sizes. See the linked article for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The code from @mihai works in most of the cases. But when there is a response with 
206 status (images, videos and audios usually in 206 response), an error will be thrown. See
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1274